# How to display image from phones gallery?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker

I'm trying to display a image on an android phone from the phones photo gallery using flutter and the /image_picker import but I keep on running into this problem:

'A value of type 'XFile?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.'

Is there anyway of converting an xfile to a file type?

here is the code coursing the problem

```
   imageSelectorGallery() async {
      galleryFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
         maxHeight: 50.0,
         maxWidth: 50.0,
      );
      setState(() {});
    }
```

here is the full code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
  
void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
  
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new GalleryAccess(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
  
class GalleryAccess extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new GalleryAccessState();
  }
}
  
class GalleryAccessState extends State<GalleryAccess> {
  late File galleryFile;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //display image selected from gallery
    imageSelectorGallery() async {
      galleryFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
        maxHeight: 50.0,
         maxWidth: 50.0,
      );
      setState(() {});
    }
  
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Gallery Access'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Text("GFG",textScaleFactor: 3,)
        ],
      ),
      body: new Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text('Select Image from Gallery'),
                  onPressed: imageSelectorGallery,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200.0,
                  width: 300.0,
                  child: galleryFile == null
                      ? Center(child: new Text('Sorry nothing selected!!'))
                      : Center(child: new Image.file(galleryFile)),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to take `galleryFile` as `XFile` type and wherever you want to use that `picked` `Xfile` then use like below code.

```
     SizedBox(
              height: 200.0,
              width: 300.0,
              child: galleryFile == null
                  ? Center(child: new Text('Sorry nothing selected!!'))
                  : Center(child: new Image.file(File(galleryFile.path))))
```